# Why doesn't code completion work for overridden methods in Android Studio?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, code-completion

Here's a picture of me overridding an on* method in an Activity descendant.

[image: no code completion happening here]

Why doesn't IntelliJ/AS try to guess as it does when I'm typing pretty much anything else?

I don't see anything obvious that's de-selected in settings:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply IntelliJ vs. Eclipse way of doing things. For me it works if I type "on" prefix without pressing Cmd+Space:

[image]

but generally it looks like "IntelliJ" way would be to use Cmd+O and Cmd+I to override or implement methods correspondingly.

Comment: Thanks; still strikes me as inconsistent that it's doesn't drop the menu after eg. `protected void onD`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why but it never worked for me either.

What i do to implement Overriden methods, or getters/setters or things like that is pressing `ctrl+enter` (in Mac, i don't know if it's the same combination in other OS), which prompts a dialog showing some options in which you can find Override:

Hope this helps you :)

(I'd have posted an image showing you but i don't have enough reputation, sorry)

Comment: That is a helpful feature to know about, thanks!  But it's still a far step away from touch-typing code completion.